# Populate matrix from a data frame via a loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, matrix

Based on a dataset (see "Input"), I would like to create the following matrix:

```
> A
   BM CC  E  F  I  S CnC D
BR  1  2  3  4  5  6 NA NA
MX  7  8 11 12 13 14  9 10
```

**Input:**

```
cntry <- c("BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "MX", "MX", "MX","MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX")
sector <- c("BM", "CC", "E", "F", "I", "S","BM", "CC", "CnC", "D", "E", "F", "I", "S")
ratio <- seq(1, 14)
data <- data.frame(cbind(cntry, sector, ratio)
```

```
> data
   cntry sector ratio
1     BR     BM     1
2     BR     CC     2
3     BR      E     3
4     BR      F     4
5     BR      I     5
6     BR      S     6
7     MX     BM     7
8     MX     CC     8
9     MX    CnC     9
10    MX      D    10
11    MX      E    11
12    MX      F    12
13    MX      I    13
14    MX      S    14
```

I tried the following but was unable to proceed further:

```
cntry_n <- nrow(cntry) # number of countries (here: 2), duplicates were removed
sector_n <- nrow(sector) # number of sectors(here: 8), duplicates were removed

A <- matrix(0, cntry_n, sector_n) # Zero was used as a default
rownames(A) <- cntry 
colnames(A) <- sector

> A
   BM CC  E  F  I  S CnC D
BR  0  0  0  0  0  0   0 0
MX  0  0  0  0  0  0   0 0

for(m in 1:cntry_n){
  for(n in 1:sector_n){
    A[m, n] = ????
  }
}
```

Is there an efficient way do solve such a problem?

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
library(tidyr)
data2 <- pivot_wider(data,names_from = sector,values_from = ratio)

# A tibble: 2 x 9
  cntry BM    CC    E     F     I     S     CnC   D    
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 BR    1     2     3     4     5     6     <NA>  <NA> 
2 MX    7     8     11    12    13    14    9     10
```

Comment: @MartinGal Yeah, do you know why that happened? I thought I did something wrong.

Comment: @Duck I don't know. Perhaps someone thought "well... that's not a matrix, so I downvote!!!!111" or that person didn't like a `tidyr` solution. In my opinion that solution answers OPs question.

Comment: @MartinGal Yeah very weird behavior!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `table` object, you can use `xtabs()`.

```
tab <- xtabs(ratio ~ cntry + sector, data)

#      sector
# cntry BM CC CnC  D  E  F  I  S
#    BR  1  2   0  0  3  4  5  6
#    MX  7  8   9 10 11 12 13 14
```

Make sure that `ratio` is numeric before using the code above.

---

To convert the table to a `data.frame`, you can use `as.data.frame.matrix()`.

```
as.data.frame.matrix(tab)

#    BM CC CnC  D  E  F  I  S
# BR  1  2   0  0  3  4  5  6
# MX  7  8   9 10 11 12 13 14
```